# Screen goes black when I run "sudo lshw"

Tags: 14.04, display

If I run the `lshw` command as user, I see what you'd expect to see.

(I won't reproduce the output here, unless someone thinks it might be useful.)

But if I run `sudo lshw`, and then count to five, both my monitors go black, with a blinking white line-cursor at the upper left of the main monitor.

My only escape from this black screen (as far as I know, though maybe there's a better way) is to press the reset button on the front of my computer.

This is on Ubuntu-MATE Trusty 14.04.5 LTS.

Would anyone know why this be happening, & how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you manage to see any error messages in the terminal? Googling around brought me to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lshw/+bug/1414476. Not sure if that is related to your problem.

Comment: Only "WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user." at beginning and end of output, without using "sudo".  The bug report is exactly what I am experiencing.  Maybe its been fixed in 16.04, but I don't know. But I don't get the "stack smashed" error message.  Only the black screen. Btw, is there a better way to exit from that?

Comment: I just noticed the bug report is a duplicate of [another one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lshw/+bug/1427436) that has a fix released.

Comment: What kernel are you running? If it's the default one, did you try to install `linux-generic-lts-xenial`?

Comment: I don't quite get this. Could you explain why I'd want to put a kernel for xenial on a trusty system?
My kernel: `--> uname -a
Linux rjbox 3.13.0-95-generic #142-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 12 17:00:09 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @watchpocket because 1) the problem looks related to drivers,  2) kernel is [actively evolving all the time](https://lwn.net/Archives/), the newer use use, the better; e.g. look at [just 4.7 changes](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.7), 3) and [because 3.13 is plainly *ancient*](https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions). And please, mention nickname with `@` in the answers, so that the one whom you answering would be notified.

Comment: @Hi-Angel This problem is insignificant compared to another problem I'm having (https://askubuntu.com/questions/822770/desktop-flickers-icons-white) on another system.  I'm concerned with it now & will get back to this one later.